# Generic plot with legend

Tags: r, function, plot, arguments, legend

What is the best way to implement a generic plot method, given that i have 2 series + legends?
The problem is that i want to provide some nice defaults for the colors and legends, but the user should be free to change it:

```
obj = list(y1 = runif(100, 0, 10), y2 = runif(100, 20, 30))
class(obj) = 'foo'

plot.foo = function(myobj, col1 = 'red', col2 = 'blue', type = 'l', ...)
{
 ylim = c(min(obj$y1, obj$y2), max(obj$y1, obj$y2))
 plot(myobj$y1, type = type, col = col1, panel.first = grid(col = '#A9A9A9'), ylim =  ylim, ...)
 lines(myobj$y2, col = col2, type = type, ...)
}

plot(obj)
```

This looks good, but if i call

```
plot(obj, col = 'black')
```

It raises an error:

```
Error in plot.foo(obj, col = "black") : 
argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Is there a way i can handle the 2 series + legends without breaking the *plot* protocol? 
(another problem is to synch the legend *lwd* and *pch* parameters)

And will CRAN reject my package if i get ride of the ... arg?
Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand your question at all. The function you defined isn't assigned to anything. Surely that's not how it appears in your actual code...?

Comment: You also haven't said what the error is, which would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a vector expected called cols with no default.  You can then add:

```
 if(missing(cols)){
      col1= "red"
      col2 = "black"
  } else {
     col1=cols[1]
     col2=cols[2]
  }
```

There are surely better ways to do it but just thought I would throw this up.

Comment: I've tried this, but then the user would need to know which series maps to each color, not very friendly...